# Convertin JsonSchema to Doctrine Enties (or Swagger, JSON)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, swagger, jsonschema, schema.org

I've been provided with a large set of JSONSchema (draft 7) describing a model of incoming messages for a SOAP API.

Based on that i have to create/generate PHP/Doctrine entities to save incoming json messages.
Because that is a large set of files, manual work is not an option. I have to build a generator.

I did some research and there are some php libraries that transform JSONSchema to a PHP model, but not to Doctrine entities.

I know there is an ApiPlatrform  project - based on Symfony (i use Symfony as well) that has a schema generator tool to generate entities.
API Platform embraces open web standards (Swagger, JSON-LD, GraphQL, Hydra, HAL, JWT, OAuth, HTTP.)  but unfortunately it doesn`t support jsonSchema.

Using this generator would be the perfect solution for me because I could go directly from JSONSchema to Doctrine+Symfony entities.

So now I'm looking for the way to transform JSONSchema to , i think it would be best for my project, to Swagger 3 (i could use Swagger later on for my API).
I didn't find any libraries or documentation that will do that.

There are some libraries that can create PHP classes (so far swaggest is best one i think), but none to create entities.

So now i have to options:

1.JSONSchema to e.g Swagger and use ApiPlatform schema generator to create entities

2.I use Swaggest to create PHP model classes and then somehow i convert it to entities

3. As a third solution i was thinking that maybe there is a way to transfor JSONSchema to mysql database and then create entities from it (there is a symfony/doctrine generator) for that (here im bit afraid of loosing some relations between tables)

Both solutions are good for me , but I think 1 is best.
So my question is , do you guys know any libraries or can you direct me to how to transform JSONSchema to Swagger ?

My goal is to have a generator that creates a nice and clean PHP Doctrine Entities with all relations and preferrably validation without any additional code (some libraries creates a lot of code on top of PHP classes)

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions

Comment: I really wander why there is -1 on this post.

Comment: https://github.com/openapi-contrib/json-schema-to-openapi-schema can convert JSON Schema to an OpenAPI schema definition

Comment: Thanks. I wil check it out.